# how i can handle icons for different screen sizes(application Ui looks fine on both phone and tablets )

Tags: android

I know to provide the icons for different screens densities, android recommended way is to provide different size icons on ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi folders.
Now the problem is that 4.7 inch device has a screen density 1.5 (hdpi) and icons look very fine.
But on a 10 inch device having a screen density of 1.5 (hdpi) icons look very small.
How should we increase the size of icons according to different screen sizes?

Comment: why negative marking of the question..?

Comment: can u post screenshots of phone and tablet?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research or minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Comment: "looks very small" -- using a ruler, are they actually the same size? In other words, do they "look very small" because they are actually smaller, or do they "look very small" because your layout is not doing something useful with the remainder of the space on the larger screen?

Comment: i tested the application and i found ,if screen density of the device is mdpi then android system always pick the icons from mdpi folder screen size does not matter.so on 4.7 inch device it looks very fine 10 inch device it looks small and on 3.2 inch device it looks large.

Comment: It is very important question.usually developer spend much of there time on the Ui so that there application looks fine on both phones and tablet.so i do not understand why this question is on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the smaller width of your tablet, you have to provide your icons in another drawable directory, called **drawable-swXYZdp**

More specifically, you can also set the resolution, so **drawable-swXYZdp-RES**

XYZ is normally 600 or 720 or 800, ...
RES is ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, ...

Those are the folders I call the "Tablet Drawables"

Comment: hi can you please suggest the icon sizes for these drawable.

Comment: hdpi resolution: 240 dpi